# Using environment variables in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, dotenv

So I've been setting up a new project and could not find any up-to-date explainations on how to do this, most people recommend to use `dotenv` but apparently `dotenv` is now included in `react-scripts`, how can I make use of this? where would I declare environment variables and how would I tell it to use production/environment ones when running my project? I know it seems like a "go read the documentation" question but I couldn't find any, and it's a pretty straight-forward question. TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add properties in `.env` file in a key-value fashion

```
AWS_CRENDETIALS='asgashgash32612'
```

and reference them in your code with `process.env.AWS_CRENDETIALS`

You can inject these properties based on the environment you are having. So when you are in production, you simply overwrite these variables. Otherwise just read from `.env` file.

I personally don't use that file, but use in development a `node` command which has all the variables. In production they are managed by Azure DevOps for example.

Answer (score 2):

Create a .env file in your root project directory with KEY=VALUE structure.
Anywhere in your src/ you can access your variable with `process.env.REACT_APP_KEY`.

`process.env` is where all your ENV's are and CRA prefixes the custom ones with `REACT_APP`